# Is $z_1^T z_1 A + z_2^T z_2 A ... + z_n^T z_n A = Z^T Z A$?

Tags: matrices

Is $z_1^T z_1 A + z_2^T z_2 A ... + z_n^T z_n A = Z^T Z A$ where the $z_1, \cdots ,z_n$ are the row vectors of the matrix $Z$ for all $n$?

The particular term appears as part of the whitening equation in the [Equivariant adaptive source separation](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Equivariant-adaptive-source-separation-Cardoso-Laheld/ca9fc6bb80d7fd89055f46d716aa8b6e2e377a5e) paper. Also a similar term also appears in [Efficient covariance matrix update for variable metric evolution strategies](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10994-009-5102-1). It is also related to [square root filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Square_root_form). Knowing that the above term holds means I could adapt the algorithm from the EASS paper for batch learning. The question itself something that could easily be verified to be true or false with a simple loop through the Z matrix and an accumulating state, but it is easier to just ask here.

Comment: As requested, the context was added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $z_k$ denotes the $k$th **row** of the matrix $Z$, then we have
$$
z_1^Tz_1A + \cdots + z_n^Tz_nA = \\
(z_1^Tz_1 + \cdots + z_n^Tz_n)A = \\
\pmatrix{z_1^T & z_2^T & \cdots & z_n ^T} \pmatrix{z_1\\z_2\\ \vdots \\ z_n}A =\\
Z^TZA
$$

Comment: On the second line that A should not be inside the expression.